# What's with the new moderator flagging abilities?

Tags: support, flags

I noticed that there is the new(and possibly brilliant if I understand it) feature that you can flag a question for closing before you have the ability to actually close. At what reputation do you gain the new flagging abilities? And who can see the posts that you flag?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/

Comment: @Robert mind phrasing that in the form of an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog entry that describes the new moderator flagging capabilities in detail is here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/

Only Diamond ♦ Moderators can see the flags.

If you do see a legitimate problem with a post, please flag it.  It helps us pull up the weeds.

Comment: I'm curious as to why only diamond mods can see the flags. Why can't everyone who is capable of voting to close?

Comment: Moderator flags are intended to address issues that are not handled by the usual mechanisms available to other users, such as close votes and delete votes.

Comment: I understand the reasoning for it for every type of flag except for the "doesn't belong here" category. I don't see why it isn't also placed in /review for users capable of closing(or even deleting) to review.